# PhpStorm and pre-commit hook with PHP-CS-Fixer which modifies number of blank lines in php file

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, pre-commit-hook, php-cs-fixer

Reproduces on Windows and Mac OS.

In our project we have pre-commit hook which runs [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) which modifies number of blank lines between methods in file (reduces from many to one). After that it makes `git add <modified_file>` to stage that change.

When we commit from PhpStorm Commit Dialog (<kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd>) it successfully commits and then causes strange state of that dialog (press <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> again after commit) with message "Contents are identical" (see first screenshot).

PhpStorm commit dialog after commit with blank lines modifications

[image: PhpStorm commit dialog after commit with blank lines modifications]

What we see if run **git status** after commit

[image: What we see if run **git status** after commit]

What we see if run **git diff** after commit

[image: What we see if run **git diff** after commit]

Note: If we commit from command line (not from PhpStorm commit dialog) all goes OK.

(**UPDATE**) Note 2: If pre-commit (php-cs-fixer) make change not related with blank lines all goes OK as well.

What we doing wrong? Is it a problem related to how PhpStorm commits? How to fix that?

Comment: It seems like external changes aren't detected by IDE (since IDE uses it's own filesystem). If you commit despite the message "contents are identical" - would it work? Would it commit right changes?

Comment: @Ástþór what interesting is that if pre-commit makes change not related with blank lines, for example change spaces number betwen braces etc, all goes OK as well.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43364) to PhpStorm bug tracker and they suggested to add post-commit hook with `git update-index -g`. I made it and it works!